# Letting jenkins execute commands as root

Tags: ssh, sudo, systemd, root

I have a jenkins server which logs into my production server via ssh and is supposed to restart some services with systemctl restart myservice.service

I've read similar issues and the most common solution was this:

```
jenkins ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart myservice.service, /bin/systemctl restart myservice2.service
```

and insert it into the sudoers file.

I have also added

```
Defaults:jenkins !requiretty
```

My deploy file does this:

```
sudo /bin/systemctl restart myservice.service
```

and then despite my efforts I still get the following error:

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

I've read about using -t when ssh'ing but I'm unsure how I would do that since I do multiple commands and some are not sudo commands.

So does anybody have a good solution for letting jenkins restart my services? I would like to avoid jenkins using root as its primary user.

Edit:

This was an issue on my side. My jenkins ssh'd into another server and is not logged in as "jenkins" so I was changing permissions for the wrong user. The solution with

```
jenkins ALL = NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl restart myservice.service, /bin/systemctl restart myservice2.service
```

works fine aslong as its the right user.

Comment: Did you find [this question, also about jenkins, sudo and this tty error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21659637/how-to-fix-sudo-no-tty-present-and-no-askpass-program-specified-error)

Comment: @MarkStosberg read my edit